# Cast to a generic type without knowing generic type

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have an interface (`ValueControl`) using a generic type and have another class (`ValueControlHandler`) which uses an instance of that interface. Now when I create `ValueControlHandler` in `CreateHandler` I need to pass the generic types. Now `TCtrl` is "easy" (I just use `ValueControl` but I don't know how to set `TVal`.

```vb
Public Interface ValueControl(Of T)
    ReadOnly Property Value As T
End Interface

Public Interface CtrlChanges
    Function HasChanges() As Boolean
End Interface

Friend Class ValueControlHandler(Of TCtrl As ValueControl(Of TVal), TVal)
    Implements CtrlChanges
    ....
End Class

Private Function DummyCreateHandler(Of TVal)(ByVal ctrl as ValueControl(Of TVal)) As CtrlChanges
    Return New ValueControlHandler(Of ValueControl(Of TVal), TVal)(ctrl)
End Function

Private Function CreateHandler(ByVal ctrl As Object) As CtrlChanges
    If TypeOf ctrl Is ValueControl(Of ValueControl(Of ???), ???) Then  ' <!--- Problem here
        Return New ValueControlHandler(Of ValueControl(Of ???), ???)(ctrl)  ' <!--- Problem here
    ElseIf Typeof ctrl Is AnotherType Then
        Return New AnotherCtrlChanges(....)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

The tricky part is, that I don't even need to know the type as I'm interested in the `CtrlChanges` part. Is the only solution to drop the generics and default to `Object`? I also tried it with `DummyCreateHandler` but then I still don't know how to check the type and it didn't really help much for the second call.

Here is the complete class from `ValueControlHandler` if this helps:

```vb
Friend Class ValueControlHandler(Of TCtrl As ValueControl(Of TVal), TVal)
    Implements CtrlChanges

    Protected ReadOnly Ctrl As TCtrl

    Protected ReadOnly Val As TVal

    Public Sub New(ByVal Ctrl As TCtrl)
        Me.Ctrl = Ctrl
        Me.Val = CurrentValue
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentValue As TVal
        Get
            Return Ctrl.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable Function HasChanges() As Boolean Implements CtrlChanges.HasChanges
        Return CType(CurrentValue, Object) <> Val
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered including a factory method as part of `ValueControl`?  (Side note, the "I" prefix on interfaces is a standard convention)

(Note, my VB.NET is a bit rusty, hopefully you can get the intent of this approach despite my typos):

```
Public Interface IValueControl(Of T)
   ReadOnly Property Value As T
   ValueControlHandler(Of T) CreateValueControlHandler(ctrl As IValueControl(Of T))
End Interface
```

Then each control can generate it's own `ValueControlHandler`:

```
Public Class MyControl Inherits Textbox Implements IValueControl(Of String)

   Public Function ValueControlHandler(Of T) CreateValueControlHandler()

      Return New ValueControlHandler(Of MyControl, String)(Me)

   End Fucntion

End Class
```

Comment: Well I marked this as the solution as this is the way I've implemented it now. A shame that there is no better way in VB.net (and probably C#), which works like `<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateHandler` could take the type to parameterize on as an argument.  Then, you would do something like this:

```
Private Function CreateHandler(ByVal ctrl As Object, ByVal TVal as Type) As CtrlChanges

    '...
    Dim genericValueControlType = GetType(ValueControl(Of )) 'Intentionally blank, the type is the unspecialized generic type.
    Dim specificValueControlType = genericValueControlType.MakeGenericType(TVal)

    'Untested, might need to be Is instead of =
    If ctrl.GetType() = specificValueControlType Then
        Dim genericHandlerType = GetType(ValueControlHandler(Of ) 'Untested, might need a comma to indicate two missing type params
        Dim specificHandlerType = genericHandlerType.MakeGenericType(specificValueControlType, TVal)
        Dim retval = specificHandlerType.GetConstructor({}).Invoke({})
        Return CType(retval, CtrlChanges)
    End If
End Function
```

Depending on the level of detail in your factory routine, you could also consider building up based on reflection and/or one or more conventions.  Unfortunately, the lack of static interface methods in .NET means that convention is the only way to invoke a logically-`Shared` routine across different implementations of an interface (that, or making something that is logically `Shared` a per-instance method anyway so that it can be put on an interface; I've done both and neither is completely satisfactory).

Comment: But now I need to know `TVal`, but then I wouldn't have the issue with the generics itself as I could use `TVal` there then, don't I?

Comment: Good point.  I've forgotten now why I thought this was a good approach for this problem; I might have just not thought it through.  It might be that the way the problem is posed, I thought at some point you would have to deal with something where you don't know `TVal` at compile time (but would be able to get it at run time).